# Trouble creating notifications in task management application using Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I am developing a task management application using Firebase Realtime Database. In my application, I store task data such as title, description, time, and date as string values.

Here is the code I am currently using to create a date and time, as well as how the task is saved and how I attempt to acquire the notification title from the "edit task" functionality

**New Task Activity (SAVE TASK BUTTON)**

```
saveButton.setOnClickListener((v) -> {


            String mTask = tskTitle.getText().toString().trim();
            String mDescription = tskDescription.getText().toString().trim();
            String id = DBrefrence.push().getKey();

            if (currentDate == null) {
                dateCurrentSelected = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
            } else if (currentDate != null) {
                dateCurrentSelected = currentDate;
            }
            if (FINAL_TIME == null) {
                TimeCurrent = timePickerBTN.getText().toString();
                //notificationtime = timePickerBTN.get
            } else if (FINAL_TIME != null) {
                TimeCurrent = FINAL_TIME;
            }
            String Time = FINAL_TIME;

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mTask)) {
                tskTitle.setError("Title Required");
                return;
            }
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mDescription)) {
                tskDescription.setError("Description Required");
                return;
            }
            else
            {

                pdLoader.setTitle("Saving Task");
                pdLoader.setMessage("Please wait");
                pdLoader.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                pdLoader.show();

                final int min = 10;
                final int max = 8000000;
                final int random = new Random().nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
                String UslID = String.valueOf(random);

                String EmptyId = "";

//
                Model model = new Model(mTask, mDescription, id, dateCurrentSelected, TimeCurrent,UslID, finalColorCard);
                DBrefrence.child(id).setValue(model).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(NewTaskActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                            Toast.makeText(NewTaskActivity.this, "Task has been successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            pdLoader.dismiss();


                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(NewTaskActivity.this, "Failed To Add Task", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            pdLoader.dismiss();
                        }

                    }
                });

            }


        });
```

*Here is How I created the Calendar and Time Picker*

**Calendar -**

```
@Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        calendarUniversal = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendarUniversal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        calendarUniversal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        calendarUniversal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(calendarUniversal.getTime());
        datePickerBTN.setText(currentDate);
    }
```

**Calendar Class -**

```
public class DatePicker extends DialogFragment
{
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int Month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity(), year, Month, day);
```

**Time Picker Dialog**

```
timePickerBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(NewTaskActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int Minute) {
                        TimeHour = hourOfDay;
                        TimeMinute = Minute;
                        calendarUniversal = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calendarUniversal.set(0, 0, 0, TimeHour, TimeMinute);
                        timePickerBTN.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("hh:mm aa", calendarUniversal));
                        FINAL_TIME = timePickerBTN.getText().toString();


                    }
                }, 12, 0, false);
                timePickerDialog.updateTime(TimeHour, TimeMinute);
                timePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });
```

**Here is the Model Class I am using for the Task Data -**

```
public class Model {

    private String task, description, id, date,time,UselessID, ColorCode;
    long notificationTime;

    public Model()
    {

    }



    public Model(String task, String description, String id, String date, String time, String UslID, String Tskcolor /*long notificationTime*/) {
        this.task = task;
        this.description = description;
        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        this.UselessID = UslID;
        this.ColorCode = Tskcolor;
//        this.notificationTime = notificationTime;

    }

    public String getTask() {
        return task;
    }

    public void setTask(String task) {
        this.task = task;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getColorCode() {return ColorCode;}

    public void setColorCode(String colorCode) {ColorCode = colorCode;}

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUselessID() {
        return UselessID;
    }

    public void setUselessID(String uselessID) {
        UselessID = uselessID;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTime() {return time;}

    public void setTime(String time) {this.time = time;}
```

Comment: You shared quite a bit of code. Specifically which line in which code fragment doesn't do what you expect it to do? For example: if you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: I want to use this code for creating notifications but I dont know how to do that

Comment: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/build-notification?